# Failure creating BizTalk application on remote server using MSBuild extension pack

Tags: biztalk, msbuildextensionpack, biztalk-deployment

I have an msbuild script that tries to create and deploy a BizTalk application to a remote server. I use the following task:

```
    <MSBuild.ExtensionPack.BizTalk.BizTalkApplication TaskAction="Create" MachineName="$(BizTalkServer)" Applications="$(BizTalkApplicationName)" />
```

When trying to deploy on a remote server, I get the following error

> error : COMException: Application registration failed because the
>   application already exists.

But that is not true, the application does not exist.

Searching on the net results in the following link, suggesting setting the MSDTC properties: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sa/biztalkediandas2/thread/251250c1-3f95-4457-8fbc-0274c722c7b0

But the DTC has been setup like this on both the local and remote server:

[image: DTC configuration]

It is also worhty of note that I run two other tasks against the remote BizTalk server to check the existence of the application, and the existence of the WCF-SQL adapter. These both succeed.

```
<MSBuild.ExtensionPack.BizTalk.BizTalkApplication TaskAction="CheckExists" MachineName="$(BizTalkServer)"  Application="$(BizTalkApplicationName)">
  <Output TaskParameter="Exists"
          PropertyName="ApplicationExists" />      
</MSBuild.ExtensionPack.BizTalk.BizTalkApplication>
<MSBuild.ExtensionPack.BizTalk.BizTalkAdaptor TaskAction="CheckExists" MachineName="$(BizTalkServer)" AdaptorName="WCF-SQL">
  <Output TaskParameter="Exists" PropertyName="AdaptorExists" />
</MSBuild.ExtensionPack.BizTalk.BizTalkAdaptor>
```

**Update**:

I inspected the event log. Don't know why I didn't think of that to begin with. I get the following 3 events:

1st event, Level=Information, Source=Sql server

> Attempting to initialize Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator
>   (MS DTC). This is an informational message only. No user action is
>   required.

2nd event, Level=Information, Source=Sql server

> The Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator (MS DTC) service
>   could not be contacted.  If you would like distributed transaction
>   functionality, please start this service.

3rd event, Level=Error, Source=BizTalk

> Unable to communicate with MessageBox BizTalkMsgBoxDb on SQL Instance
>   .. Error Code: 0x8004d01c. Possible reasons include:
>   1) The MessageBox is unavailable.
>   2) The network link from this machine to the MessageBox is down.
>   3) The DTC Configuration on either this local machine or the machine hosting this MessageBox is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  discovered that although there is no BizTalk application on the remote server, the one I'm attempting to deploy to, with that name, there was a BizTalk application on the local server, the one I'm attempting to deploy from, with the specified name.

That shouldn't prevent me from deploying the application to a remote server but it does.

This behavior is present both when I use the MSBuild extension pack BizTalk tasks, and when I try to use btstask.exe to create a remote application.